# Custom Blog Post Listing in Genesis Sample Child Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, hooks, page-template, genesis-theme-framework

I want to add several images and divs and also customize the look of my Blog post listing... But i can't find the way to do it.

Here's the Blog Template code

```
<?php
/*
 WARNING: This file is part of the core Genesis framework. DO NOT edit
 this file under any circumstances. Please do all modifications
 in the form of a child theme.
 */

/**
 * Template Name: Blog
 * This file handles blog post listings within a page.
 *
 * This file is a core Genesis file and should not be edited.
 *
 * The blog page loop logic is located in lib/structure/loops.php
 *
 * @category Genesis
 * @package  Templates
 * @author   StudioPress
 * @license  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GPL v2.0 (or later)
 * @link     http://www.studiopress.com/themes/genesis
 */
genesis();
```

and just above the `genesis();` code.. i tried to put some divs and images there.. But i guess that's not the way it works. ..

I also tried to make my own Blog listing template using a normal wordpress code theme..

```
<?php /* 
Template Name: List Post Pages
*/ 
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div id="content" class="hfeed">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="postmetadata">
      <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
      Posted in
      <?php the_category(', ') ?>
      |
      <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else : ?>
  <h2>Not Found</h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But no luck, what's the right way to do this?

***Update -code below is the one i want.. but instead of having the Content of the page. I want the list of Post with excerpts ....How can i do that????

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Page Template
*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<?php genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">
  <?php genesis_before_content(); ?>
  <div id="content" class="hfeed">
    <?php genesis_before_loop(); ?>
    <?php genesis_loop(); ?>
    <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- end #content -->
  <?php genesis_after_content(); ?>
</div>
<!-- end #content-sidebar-wrap -->
<?php genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this pretty much all wrong. You should read the instructions before continuing.

[An Introduction to Child Themes](http://studiopress.tv/intro-to-hooks/)
[An Introduction to Hooks in the Genesis Framework for WordPress](http://my.studiopress.com/docs/hooks/)

The second code you provided can be rewritten as this:

```
// Template Name: Page Template

genesis();
```

That's it. Genesis takes care of all that stuff you just wrote. But you need to read the instruction. [Watch the video](http://studiopress.tv/intro-to-hooks/) in the second link. You are making this much harder than it has to be.

> ***Update ... instead of having the Content of the page. I want the list of Post[s] with excerpts .... [sic] How can [I] do that?

I couldn't stand the idea of naming a page template `Page Template`.

```
<?php

// Template Name: Excerpts

// Replace the loop.
remove_action(  'genesis_loop',   'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop',   'genesis_custom_loop' );

// Change the content archive and loop args.
add_action( 'genesis_pre_get_option_content_archive', 'child_post_content_archive' );
add_filter( 'genesis_custom_loop_args', 'child_loop_args' );

genesis();

/**
 * Change default content to excerpts on this page.
 */
function child_post_content_archive() {
    return 'excerpts';
}

/**
 * Use WP_Query args.
 *
 * @link {http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query}
 */
function child_loop_args() {

    return array(
        posts_per_page => 5,
    );
}
```

Comment: A small correction ```posts_per_page``` should be in quotes